# Adding New Requirement in the middle of the sprint

Tags: scrum, agile, sprint

1
If you are in the middle of the sprint and the product owner has come with the one new requirement for the customer what do you do? What is the best way to handle it? How to evaluate the scrum team?

2   IF you are in the middle of sprint and the product owner has come with the one new requirement for the customer what do you do? What is the best way to handle it? How can I handle security in Agile product development?

Comment: Your question needs some serious cleanup. You've got two points, each consisting of two related and one unrelated question. The related questions are repeated in your two points. The other questions don't seem to be related to the middle-of-sprint question, you might want to separate them (with sufficient context, as they are now they are not suitable).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can sprint backlog change while sprint is running?](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/28026/can-sprint-backlog-change-while-sprint-is-running)

Answer (score 2):

New requirements come up all the time and go on the backlog for future sprints but I expect you mean the PO wants to add it to the *current* sprint. The PO should have the final say about the goal of the sprint. Given that you are half way through I would expect a conversation between the PO and the development team to work out what the impact will be. Maybe only part of the new item can be achieved by the end of the sprint or maybe other parts of the sprint goal should be dropped in favour of the new item.

The team should also try to understand why this new requirement didn't come up during sprint planning. Perhaps stakeholder feedback isn't being gathered as effectively as it could be or perhaps the sprint is too long, making it harder to forecast or respond to changing priorities. It's interesting that you make a distinction between PO and customer. The PO is the customer as far as the development team are concerned. Perhaps there is some disconnect here that is relevant to your question.

I don't understand your second question. What do you mean by "security" in this context?